# VS2010 Report Design: CountDistinct function with qualifying parameter?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a C# program that generates a report (designed using the Report Design wizard) that looks like this:

[image: expanded report]

It has six columns: BILLMOYR, MBRSEP, LOCATION, RATE, BILLTYPE, DISTRICT.

At the bottom of this report, I have an expression that looks like this:

```
[CountDistinct(MBRSEP)]
```

This tells me the total number of unique MBRSEPs in my report.

What I'd also like to do is get the total number of unique MBRSEPs for each DISTRICT.  Can I add something to the report like this?:

```
[CountDistinct(MBRSEP where DISTRICT = '13')]
[CountDistinct(MBRSEP where DISTRICT = '14')]
```

etc...?  Does something like that exist for the CountDistinct function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple in RS.  You simply create a grouping for MBRSEP and in the group footer you can leave COUNTDISTINCT(MBRSEP).  You are using reporting services correct?
This will give you a count per each group.

Comment: I actually designed the report in the Visual Studio 2010 Report designer wizard.  I'm not very familiar with these type of reports, so I'm learning as I go along.  As far as creating a MBRSEP 'grouping', I'll investigate how to do that and see if it helps me determine the unique MBRSEPS by DISTRICT.

Comment: @Kevin - here is an example of creating a group within the report http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389884/how-do-you-create-a-report-rdlc-that-shows-1-record-per-page/8390250#8390250