# RDLC Report not paging with dynamically bound datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc

I have a rdlc report I want to bind a list of my own custom class to as a data source.

I've used some code recommended on [this site](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aconrad/archive/2007/09/07/science-project.aspx) to build the DataTable

This works really well

```
     //convert my list of Invoices to a DataTable
     var dt = invoices.CopyToDataTable(dataTable, LoadOption.PreserveChanges);
     //Setup a new DataSource
     var rds = new ReportDataSource {Name = "ReportDataSet", Value = dt};
     //Add that datasource to my ReportViewer
     rvSampleInvoice.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
     //Map my report path, etc
     rvSampleInvoice.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("etc");
```

This all works fine, when I load my page, the report shows, but it only has one 2 pages. the first is the first entry in my invoices collection, and when I click next page, it's a blank page.
I've added a gridview to the page, and bound the DataTable (dt) to it and it displays as a nice table with a row of headers and 20 rows of data.

I'm wondering if I've got something wrong on how to bind a RDLC to my List of Invoices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389884/how-do-you-create-a-report-rdlc-that-shows-1-record-per-page) has has solved the issue. There's gotta be a better way of doing this, so if anyone knows a better way to have multiple pages for one result set, let me know

Update:

Ok, I'll explain what I've learnt now more about RDLCs for future archeologists. You can't just drag and drop data into a page, bind a list of items and expect it to duplicate the sample page you've made however many times there are items in your list.
You need to drag a table into the report and tick the "page break" option in the SO solution I linked to. Then stretch the table across the page, add a bunch of rows and columns. The fill in the cells you want in your page.
It takes a bunch of cell merging and stretching to get it to look the way I want, so if there's a better way, someone please make a post.